# 404 The requested resource is not available for idea, tomcat and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have problem with starting jsp files in the project for intellij idea, Tomcat 8.5. I pretty sure it is configuration issue but I have already checked it and it is still doesn't want to work.

[Please see project structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV0LU.png)

[Tomcat artifact configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmR9s.png)

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

</web-app>
```

Comment: Default folder for web resources is `webapp` not `WebApp`. And jsps should be placed directly under `webapp` not under `WEB-INF` folder

Comment: Is web resource root directory configured for the module?

Comment: I renamed 'WebApp'  to 'webapp'. But it didn't help. All jsps directly under webapp not WEB-INF folder.